# Initialization of UITableViewCell Fails (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm using a `tableView` and try to create my `cells`.. in vain. 
I set all the things we have to do (created a prototype cell, gave an identifier ("CustomerCell"), set the `delegate` and `dataSource` in the `storyBoard` and inside the `ViewDidLoad` both, set the good class in the `StoryBoard` for the `tableView`, the `cells`, etc).

Here's my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
}


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let item = items[indexPath.section]
    switch item.type {

    case .customer:

        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomerCell", for: indexPath) as? CustomerCellSetter {
            cell.item = item as? Customer // THIS is never called, the cell return nil all the time
            return cell
        }

    return UITableViewCell()
 }
```

[image: cell ID]

[image: Delegates]

Is there an other parameter in the equation to get my cell? 
Thanks in advance for your precious help !

EDIT:

here's my `UITableViewCell` classes:

```
class CustomerCellSetter: CustomerTableViewCell {
var item: Customer? {
    didSet {
        guard let item = item else {
            return }
        if let firstName = item.firstName {
            fisrtName?.text = firstName
        }

        if let theLastName = item.lastName {
            lastName.text = theLastName
        }

        if let theGsm = item.GSM {
            gsm.text = theGsm
        }

        if let theMail = item.mail {
            mail.text = theMail
        }

        if let theAdress = item.adress {
            adress.text = theAdress
        }

        if let theNote = item.notes {
            notes.text = theNote
        }

    }
}

}




class CustomerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


@IBOutlet var fisrtName : UILabel!
@IBOutlet var lastName : UILabel!
@IBOutlet var gsm : UILabel!
@IBOutlet var mail : UILabel!
@IBOutlet var adress : UILabel!
@IBOutlet var notes : UILabel!




override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}

}
```

EDIT 2:

[image]

Comment: Did you added tableView.reload() method ..?

Comment: I can try but this just RE load the data. Where do you think I need to add it?

Comment: Put that method in viewWillAppear..

Comment: Did your tableView class subclass from `tableViewDataSource` and `tableViewDelegate`

Comment: @ andesta.erfan yes

Comment: And please add screenshot of uitableviewcell's class name in uistoryboard

Comment: @ MAhipal Singh I tried , but didn't works

Comment: @ MAhipal Singh Added a screenshot in "Edit 2"

Comment: It needs to be `CustomCellSetter`, not `CustomerTableViewCell`.

Comment: @ OOPer  thank you very much ... I fell like an idiot now. I will delete this post. Thank you again !

Comment: @ OOPer I can't delete the post. You can re write your comment as an answer not a comment to mark it.

Comment: Have you implemented the __numberOfRowsInSection__ data source method? Check what value does this method return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to set CustomCellSetter, not CustomerTableViewCell in identity inspector. Thanks @OOPer for this simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

did you set the class for the cell as "CustomerCellSetter"?

This can be done in the identity inspector.

Comment: I updated my question with my UITableViewCell classes. 
I set the class "CustomerTableViewCell" in the identity inspector. do you think the issue might comes over there?

Comment: I don't know if it is important to set both identity inspector and code casting to same type. Have you tried to set the class in the identity inspector to "CustomerCellSetter". At last you cast the dequeueReusableCell to "CustomerCellSetter"

Comment: @Matt, It IS super-important. With setting `CustomerTableViewCell`, IB runtime tries to create an instance of `CustomerTableViewCell`, not `CustomerCellSetter `. Which cannot be converted with `as?`-casting, so it returns `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have add "UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource" at class name ?

```
class ClassName: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

}
```

and also you need to add more method of tableview

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return 1 // number of your rows
}
```